# get a list of stocks that i still own Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that contain my activity in the stock market. here is an example of the tablet:

| Date (A) | Action (B) | Symbol (C) | Shares (D) | Price (E) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/1/2022 | BUY | AAPL | 100 | 100 |
| 01/1/2022 | SELL | AAPL | 90 | 100 |
| 01/1/2022 | BUY | TSLA | 100 | 100 |
| 01/1/2022 | BUY | GOOG | 100 | 100 |
| 01/1/2022 | SELL | GOOG | 100 | 100 |
| 01/1/2022 | SELL | TSLA | 99 | 100 |

I want to make a formula that returns a list of the Symbols of the stocks I still own shares of.
for example I can buy 100 shares of GOOG and than sell 99 of them so I still own shares of GOOG so it should appear in the list. also I can sell all my GOOG shares and them it shouldn't appear no longer in the list.

The return of the table I added should be TSLA AAPL

I tried using chatgpt but it's banned here so I can't tell. I only can say that it didn't gave me a proper formula

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfJjq.png)

Comment: First you need to know if you are using Google sheets or Excel.

Comment: Made it clear, I'm using google sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY({IF(B2:B="SELL",-1,1)*D2:D,C2:C},"select sum(Col1), Col2 group by Col2"),"select Col2 where Col1<>0"))
```

We are turning the shares corresponding to `SELL` negative then we are doing a conditional sum with QUERY and filtering out the non-zeros.

Comment: It did work for the table I put but in my real table it does not work propery it shows some of the symbols that I have 0 shares of

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my table and the result is: AMD
AMZN
GE
GOOGL

Comment: You can take for example GE it has only 3 rows

Comment: can you share the sheet?